# chrome extension to remove div on facebook

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i'm new on chrome extensions!
i need help to create my personal extension for the sims social on facebook!!

I won't to remove the right column and some ads with my extension!!

manifest.json

```
    {
"name":"The Sims Social noAds",
"version":"1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description":"Rimuovere tutto quello che non serve dalla pagina del gioco The sims   Social",
"content_scripts":[{
"matches":["http://apps.facebook.com/thesimssocial/*"],
"js":["script.js"]
}]}
```

script.js

```
document.querySelector('div.rightCol').style.display = 'none';
```

Someone can help me!??!? TNX!!

Answer (score 2):

rightCol is the *id* of the div instead of the *class name*. Therefore, you should use `document.querySelector('#rightCol')` instead.

For the syntax of the selectors, Google *css selectors* or take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp . You can also right-click the target element and choose *Inspect Element*, and you'll see those selectors below.
[image]

Comment: now, i won't to remove div without id but have class like <div class="pf-console-footer">....</div>.... how to? TNX!

Comment: ``document.querySelector('#rightCol').remove()``?